# Cannot extend class in PHP using Late Static Binding when including or requiring external file

Tags: php, database, web

Here's the source class:

```
require_once('database.php');

class DatabaseObject {

    public static function find_all()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM " .static::$dbName;
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            echo "<div class = user>";
            echo "Name: {$row['first_name']} {$row['last_name']} <br/>";
            echo "E-Mail: {$row['email']} <br/>";
            echo "Username: {$row['username']} <br/>";
            echo "Password: {$row['password']}";
            echo "</div> <hr/>";
        }
    }


}
```

And here's the inheriting class:

```
require_once('database.php');
require('databaseobject.php');

class User extends DatabaseObject{

    public $id;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $emai;
    public $username;
    public $password;

    public static $dbValues = array(
        'id','first_name','last_name',
        'email','username','password'
    );
    public static $dbName = 'users';

}

User::find_all();
```

After trying to run user.php I get the following output:

```
> "; echo "E-Mail: {$row['email']} 
"; echo "Username: {$row['username']} 
"; echo "Password: {$row['password']}"; echo "
"; } } } ?>
Fatal error: Class 'DatabaseObject' not found in C:\wamp\www\library\includes\user.php on line 5
```

Does anyone have any idea of what's going on???? Everything works fine if the DatabaseObject class is in the same file as the user class thouth... not sure whats going on with the include.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. What makes you think that *Class 'DatabaseObject'* should be found?

Comment: side note: for LSB use `static` instead of `self` when referencing `$dbName` in `DatabaseObject` http://php.net/lsb#language.oop5.late-static-bindings.usage

Comment: You shouldn't be using mysql_* functions anymore, they're deprecated, they're not designed to work with MySQL 5, and they'll be removed from the language sooner or later.  Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: I did try using static:: instead of self:: got the same error.

Comment: Oswald: Well the file with the User class does have a require("databaseobject.php")... everything works if I bring the class into the same file. Something is wrong with the include, that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Can you tell us the PHP version installed? I'm having success with PHP 5.4.17.

Comment: How about dropping this late static binding stuff becouse you are doing a really ugly hack here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very embarrassed to say that I was missing the ?php tag at the top of the DatabaseObject.php file. Sorry for wasting everyone's time. :(